# How to prevent horizontal dropdown menu from creating scroll bars as the page is resized?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive

I have a menu with drop down lists that are arranged horizontally. I would like them to not overflow the page width when i resize the browser size. I would like them to move with the page resizing rather than overflowing and creating scroll bars? Not too sure how to go about this without using a lot of media queries? or is this the only/correct way to do it?

```css
.header-menu-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.headermenu {
  padding: 0 10% 0 10%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #17D8C7;
}

.headermenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.headermenu>ul>li>a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.headermenu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.headermenu .arrow {
  line-height: 0%;
  font-size: 8px
}

.headermenu>ul>li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: 0.5%;
  margin-right: 0.5%;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.headermenu>ul>li>div {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #d0d1d2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 450px;
  background-color: white;
}

.headermenu>ul>li:hover>div {
  display: block;
}

.headermenu>ul>li>a:hover {
  color: #6E0089;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.left,
.middle,
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 5px;
  border-right: 1px solid lightgray;
  height: 337.44px
}

.submenu div:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.submenu>div>ul>li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.submenu>div>ul>li:hover>a {
  color: rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.85);
  transition: all .5s;
}

.submenu h3 {
  color: #6e0089;
  font-size: 1.05em;
}

.submenu a {
  color: #17d8c7;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.right {
  border-right: none;
}

#lastsubmenu {
  margin-left: -210px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#lastsubmenu>.left,
#lastsubmenu>.middle,
#lastsubmenu>.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}

#tapsubmenu {
  margin-left: -420px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#tapsubmenu>.left,
#tapsubmenu>.middle,
#tapsubmenu>.right {
  width: 25%;
  height: 200px;
}

#showersubmenu {
  margin-left: -100px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#showersubmenu>.left,
#showersubmenu>.middle,
#showersubmenu>.right {
  width: 50%;
}

#furnituresubmenu {
  margin-left: -200px;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#furnituresubmenu>.left,
#furnituresubmenu>.middle,
#furnituresubmenu>.right {
  width: 33.3%;
}

#showerenclosuresubmenu {
  margin-left: -350px;
  width: 750px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#showerenclosuresubmenu>.left,
#showerenclosuresubmenu>.middle,
#showerenclosuresubmenu>.right {
  width: 20%;
}

#basinsubmenu {
  margin-left: -200px;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#basinsubmenu>.left,
#basinsubmenu>.middle,
#basinsubmenu>.right {
  width: 33.3%;
  height: 200px;
}

#toiletsubmenu {
  margin-left: -200px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#toiletsubmenu>.left,
#toiletsubmenu>.middle,
#toiletsubmenu>.right {
  width: 25%;
}

#bathsubmenu {
  margin-left: -100px;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#bathsubmenu>.left,
#bathsubmenu>.middle,
#bathsubmenu>.right {
  width: 25%;
}


/* Main NAVBAR and Header Resposive */

@media screen and (max-width: 905px) {
  .search-container,
  li.accountbutton,
  li.basketbutton {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 905px) {
  .mainheader {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1053px) {
  .headermenu {
    height: 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="header-menu-wrap">
  <nav class="headermenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">ON SALE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Suites</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Baths<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div id="bathsubmenu" class="submenu">
          <div class="left">
            <ul class="bathdropdown1">
              <h3>Bath Types</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Standard</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">L-Shaped</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">B-Shaped</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="middle">
            <ul class="bathdropdown2">
              <h3>Bath Accessories</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Bath Screens</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bath Panels</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <ul class="bathdropdown3">
              <h3>All Baths</h3>
              <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right submenuimage">
            <a href="#"><img src="bathsubmenuimage.png"></img>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Toilets<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div id="toiletsubmenu" class="submenu">
          <div class="left">
            <ul class="toiletdropdown1">
              <h3>Toilet Style</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Back to Wall</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Close Coupled</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Comfort Height</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Fully Back to Wall</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Low Level</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Toilet and Basin Units</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="middle">
            <ul class="toiletdropdown2">
              <h3>Toilet Accessories</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Concealed Cisterns</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <ul class="toiletdropdown3">
              <h3>All Toilet Types</h3>
              <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right submenuimage">
            <a href="#"><img src="toiletsubmenuimage.png"></img>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Basins<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div id="basinsubmenu" class="submenu">
          <div class="left">
            <ul class="basindropdown1">
              <h3>Style</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Basin and Pedestal</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Cloakroom</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <ul class="basindropdown2">
              <h3>All Basins</h3>
              <li><a href="#">All Basins</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right submenuimage">
            <a href="#"><img src="basinsubmenuimage.png"></img>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Shower Enclosures<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div id="showerenclosuresubmenu" class="submenu">
          <div class="left showerenclosureleft">
            <ul class="showerenclosuredropdown1">
              <h3>Amelia Enclosures</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Amelia Bifold Door</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Amelia Enclosure Side Panels</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Amelia Pivot Door</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Amelia Quadrant Enclosure</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Amelia Sliding Door</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="middle showerenclosuremiddle">
            <ul class="showerenclosuredropdown2">
              <h3>Sienna Enclosures</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Sienna Quadrant</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sienna Bifold Door</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sienna Pivot Door</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sienna Sliding Door</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sienna Wet Room Screen</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sienna Enclosure Side Panels</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="middle showerenclosuremiddle">
            <ul class="showerenclosuredropdown3">
              <h3>Show Trays</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Shower Trays</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Riser Kits</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right showerenclosureright">
            <ul class="showerenclosuredropdown4">
              <h3>All Enclosures</h3>
              <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right submenuimage">
            <a href="#"><img src="showerenclosuresubmenuimage.png"></img>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Furniture<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div id="furnituresubmenu" class="submenu">
          <div class="left">
            <ul class="furnituredropdown1">
              <h3>Collection</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Bella Collection</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Caprice Collection</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Gino Collection</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Shine Collection</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sienna Collection</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Valentino Collection</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <ul class="furnituredropdown2">
              <h3>Unit Type</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Vanity Unit and Basin</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Wall Vanity Unit and Basin</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Corner Vanity Unit and Basin</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Back to Wall Units</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Cupboard Units</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mini Units</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right submenuimage">
            <a href="#"><img src="furnituresubmenuimage.png"></img>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Showers<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div id="showersubmenu" class="submenu">
          <div class="right">
            <ul class="showersdropdown1">
              <h3>Style</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Round Head</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Square Head</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right submenuimage">
            <a href="#"><img src="showersubmenuimage.png"></img>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Taps<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div id="tapsubmenu" class="submenu">
          <div class="left">
            <ul class="tapsdropdown1">
              <h3>Bathroom Taps</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Mono Mixer</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bath Shower Mixer</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mini Mono Mixer</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bath Filler</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="middle">
            <ul class="tapsdropdown2">
              <h3>Kitchen Taps</h3>
              <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right">
            <ul class="tapsdropdown3">
              <h3>All Taps</h3>
              <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right submenuimage">
            <a href="#"><img src="tapsubmenuimage.png"></img>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Accessories<span class="arrow">&#9660;</span></a>
        <div id="lastsubmenu" class="submenu">
          <div class="right">
            <ul class="accessoriesdropdown1">
              <h3>All Accessories</h3>
              <li><a href="#">Wastes</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="right submenuimage">
            <a href="#"><img src="accessoriesubmenuimage.png"></img>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Please ignore the lack of images, they are just 150px wide category images.

Any help would be great and a explanation would obviously be awesome.

Thanks in advance

James

Comment: You need a script that calculate the offset and push the sub menu to the right place.

Comment: ah ok a script, like a js script?

Comment: No like, js script :)